# Handling exceptions thrown by ASP.NET Core filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, error-handling

I use a lot of asp.net core filters.
I'm looking for elegant way to handle exceptions that can be thrown by filters.

For example filter like that:

```
public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context){
     Convert.ToInt32("NotConvertable");
}
```

will throw FormatException which will crush entire application, which is not cool.
I'd like to log error, return 500 but without app crush.

I tried to add middleware before MVC:

```
try
{
    await _next(context);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError("FATAL ERROR", ex);
}
```

but it didnt't help, still crushing.

I'm thinking about make try{}catch with returning 500 with some kind of logging in each filter, but that will lead to large number of repetitions.

Is it any way to handle it globally ?

More context

```
  public class PermissionAttribute:TypeFilterAttribute
  {
       public PermissionAttribute():base(typeof(PermissionFilter))
       {
       }
  }

 public class PermissionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
 {
      public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
      {
           Convert.ToInt32("NotConvertable");
      }
 }
```

And controller:

```
[Route("api/nav/")]
public class AController : Controller{

    ...

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    [PermissionAttribute]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SomeClass), 200)]
    public async Task<SomeClass> GetAll()
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Calling this endpoint crush entire process

Startup.cs (shorted)
public void Configure(...some services){

```
... some app.Use UseLogger, HealthCheck
app.UseMiddleware<PleaseDontCrushMiddleware>(); // Middleware mentioned above
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorHandler.Handle);

a lot of middlewares

app.UseMvc(RouteTable);
```

}

MVC Service is added this way:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            config.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheFilter(new CacheProfile()
            {
                NoStore = true,
                Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None
            }, 
            services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILoggerFactory()));
         }
```

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Edited, I use ASP.NET Core

Comment: Can you show your Startup.cs and Controller where you use the filter - give us some more context?

Comment: @IMujagic extended

Comment: Sorry but I don't see your Startup.cs. But in general, make sure your Exception Middleware is the first one in the pipeline. Remember that order matters when you are registering your middlewares in Startup.cs

Comment: @IMujagic i have a lot of middlewares, but exception handling are before most of them.  When i using debugger i have my middleware in callstack calling _next

Comment: when exception happens, if it can be recovered, your code (as close as possible to the point throwing the exception) must handle it. Otherwise (either the error cannot be recovered or simply let handled by some global handler), you can't just nicely log it and not care about the result page. I mean in such cases an ***error page*** should be shown (for ajax requests, a response containing the error message can be returned). The error in your example is a kind of unrecoverable error, an error page should be shown in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you will throw some specific exceptions in some methods while other you just want to catch as System.Exception maybe you can use this approach:

You can create Exception handling extension method (if you want to use Logger too just add ILogger parameter in the method and pass it from Startup.Configure):

```
public static class ExceptionHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public static void UseCustomExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(eApp =>
            {
                eApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                    var errorCtx = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (errorCtx != null)
                    {
                        var ex = errorCtx.Error;
                        var message = "Unspecified error ocurred.";
                        var traceId = traceIdentifierService.TraceId;

                        if (ex is ValidationException)
                        {
                            var validationException = ex as ValidationException;
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                            message = string.Join(" | ", validationException.Errors.Select(v => string.Join(",", v.Value)));
                        }
                        else if (ex is SomeCustomException)
                        {
                            var someCustomException = ex as SomeCustomException;
                            ...
                        }

                        var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ErrorResponse
                        {
                            TraceId = traceId,
                            Message = message
                        });
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResponse, Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

And then you just register it in Startup Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            ...

            app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();

            ...
        }
```

About exceptions in Authorization filters (from microsoft docs):

> Do not throw exceptions within authorization filters:
>
> ```
> The exception will not be handled.
> Exception filters will not handle the exception.
> ```
>
> Consider issuing a challenge when an exception occurs in an
> authorization filter

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters

Comment: I'm using custom ExceptionHandler, but it isn't called when exception comes from filter/attribute. Process dies before it

Comment: I updated my answer. You should not throw an exception from Authorization filters, they won't be handled. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It gets error because of `async void`. use `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` and it will be resolved.