# ErrorController not invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I tried to customize the default behavior in order that I can change what gets returned in case of an exception inside my API controller.

I applied what I read inside the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "todo_list_app v1"));
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    }
    [...]
}
```

**ErrorController.cs:**

```
[ApiController]
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/error-local-development")]
    public IActionResult ErrorLocalDevelopment(
            [FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        if (webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName != "Development")
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "This shouldn't be invoked in non-development environments.");
        }

        var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

        return Problem(detail: context.Error.StackTrace, title: context.Error.Message);
        }

    [Route("/error")]
    public IActionResult Error() => Problem();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you would rather use some custom exception handler, you can check example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222731/handling-exceptions-thrown-by-asp-net-core-filters/66224132#66224132

Comment: Looks good, but I would like to understand why the original does not work in my case.

Comment: Are you running locally on your development environment?

Comment: I work locally but I built the release and caused an exception on purpose by renaming a table in my database.

Comment: what if you try visiting `/error` directly?

Answer (score 1):

Your `app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");` implies that unhandled exceptions will be caught by your `ErrorController`. You don't need the `/` in your  `[Route("/error")]` it should just be `[Route("error")]`.

I would recommend that you implement a body here to actually catch your exceptions and do whatever it is you want with them. Take a look at a very basic example that I wrote:

```
[Route("error")]
public ErrorResponseModel Error()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
    var exception = context.Error;

    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    return new ErrorResponseModel(exception);
}
```

This will catch your exception and then attach a `500` error to it. I user a custom model here, but you could return anything you wanted. You can also extend this functionality a bit more and check your type of exception and return different error codes depending on your exception type.

Answer (score 0):

For what I wanted to achieve I had to call the **UseExceptionHandler** in development mode as well.

```
//app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-local-development");
```

However, in the release mode, I did not expect that

```
 public IActionResult Error() => Problem();
```

would return *nothing* but an HTTP code. Which is no different than when having no route at all.