# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : error handling action in a custom base controller

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-webapi

I followed [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about error handling in a controller based ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, with a little difference - I defined a base controller in order to define the error handling actions in a single place.

When I make an http request to an action that throws an exception, the error handling function is not being executed (neither in a development env nor in a prod env).

If I write the actions in the same controller the exception is thrown the code is being reached.

Why?

BaseController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{

[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[Route("/error-development")]
public IActionResult HandleErrorDevelopment([FromServices] IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
    if (!hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var exceptionHandlerFeature =
        HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()!;

    return Problem(
        detail: exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.StackTrace,
        title: exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.Message);
}

[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[Route("/error")]
public IActionResult HandleError() =>
        Problem();
}
```

ValuesController.cs:

```
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        throw new Exception("Sample exception.");
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-development");
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073211/errorcontroller-not-invoked

Check out that thread and please also comb over this sample referenced in the docs you linked: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/web-api/handle-errors/samples/6.x/HandleErrorsSample

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Route of the entire controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

I Ended up moving the 2 error actions to a seperate controller, which I didn't mark with a Route attribute, and it works as expected.

```
[ApiController]
public class ErrorsController : ControllerBase
{
    ILogger<ErrorsController> logger;
    public ErrorsController(ILogger<ErrorsController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    [Route("/error")]
    public ActionResult Error([FromServices] IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        var exceptionHandlerFeature =
            HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        logger.LogError(exceptionHandlerFeature?.Error.ToString());

        return Problem(
            detail: "Please try later...",
            title: "Sorry...");

    }
    [Route("/error-development")]
    public ActionResult DevelopmentError([FromServices] IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        var exceptionHandlerFeature =
            HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        logger.LogError(exceptionHandlerFeature?.Error.ToString());

        return Problem(
            detail: exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.StackTrace,
            title: exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.Message);

    }
}
```